# Intermittent Event code 3005 error VS 2010 Express VB.NET

Tags: .net

I have a VB.NET app that works fine on my development machine, but generates an intermittent error on my server. The Event log is below (sorry if this is more than what needs to be posted, but one of my problems is interpreting the event log).

It appears that the error occurs on the server when two or more people simultaneously run the web app. Often it looks like it is hung and then times out. Then if I try to go back to run the app, I get the error below until I restart the website on the server. So far, no problems if only one person is running the app. My server vendor indicates that this indicates it is an app error (as opposed to memory, server, etc). The app grabs input data, queries several MS Access databases (using ADODB) and returns some values thru AJAX. It is a fairly intensive calcs app that takes several seconds to run.

I know I should provide the code where the error is generated, but my first problem is that I am not sure how to read the event log. **Where is this telling me that the error event occurs?** I assume that it has something to do with hitting the database?

Currently, it is only reading data, so I am assuming it can't be that the database gets locked somehow? I don't believe I ever have more than one connection open or more than one recordset open and that I open/close with each database query (again, it works on the dev machine). So it seems like it must have something to do with multiple users?

**In general, I assumed I don't need to worry about people hitting the database or the app simultaneously? Or is this expected, ie do I need to always have a Try/Catch around the offending code (as soon as I figure out what code is offending) to catch these errors?**

Also, I don't know if this is normal or related to the problem - The event log shows paths that are not from the server, but from my development machine (those that start with C:\MyFiles...). How does the server know those paths? Is this something that is stored in the binary DLLs that get uploaded to the server?

Again, I apologize in advance if I missed providing more info. But maybe these preliminary questions can get me closer to the source of the problem. This seems like a useful forum.

Thanks in advance,
Chuck

*Note: some of the IP addresses have been masked*

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0
Date:          8/6/2013 2:48:00 PM
Event ID:      1309
Task Category: Web Event
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      358797-web1
Description:
Event code: 3005

Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.
Event time: 8/6/2013 2:48:00 PM 

Event time (UTC): 8/6/2013 7:48:00 PM 

Event ID: ca3280fb485345c194349a42e6e81a85 

Event sequence: 66 

Event occurrence: 11 

Event detail code: 0 


Application information: 

Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/12/ROOT-1-130202909916484475 

Trust level: Full 

Application Virtual Path: / 

Application Path: C:\inetpub-illustrations\wwwroot\ 

Machine name: 358797-WEB1 


Process information: 

Process ID: 760 

Process name: w3wp.exe 

Account name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 


Exception information: 

Exception type: COMException 

Exception message: Operation is not allowed when the object is open.

   at ADODB.ConnectionClass.set_ConnectionString(String pbstr)
   at clsCalc_IllustrationValues.mod_DLLUtilities.util_OpenMyDBConnection(String& strDBName,
   String& strPassword) in C:\MyFiles\Visual Studio Projects   
   \clsCalc_IllustrationValues\mod_DLLUtilities.vb:line 130
   at clsCalc_IllustrationValues.clsConvertedActVal.GetPlanData(Int32& eLOB_ActValCalcs, 
   usrUserInputType& usrUserInput, usrPolicyValuesType&    usrPolicyValues) in C:\MyFiles\Visual 
   Studio Projects\clsCalc_IllustrationValues\clsConvertedActVal.vb:line 2668
   at clsCalc_IllustrationValues.clsConvertedActVal.TradSolve() in C:\MyFiles\Visual Studio 
   Projects\clsCalc_IllustrationValues\clsConvertedActVal.vb:line    2063
   at clsCalc_IllustrationValues.clsActValDotNet.DoSingleSolve(DataSet dsDataSet) in
   C:\MyFiles\Visual Studio Projects\clsCalc_IllustrationValues   \clsActValDotNet.vb:line 945
   at _Default.CallSingleSolve() in C:\inetpub-illustrations\wwwroot\Default.aspx.vb:line 2997
   at _Default.InitializeAllControls() in C:\inetpub-illustrations\wwwroot\Default.aspx.vb:line
   354
   at _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\inetpub-
   illustrations\wwwroot\Default.aspx.vb:line 65
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)




Request information: 

Request URL: http://xx.xx.xx.250/Default.aspx 

Request path: /Default.aspx 

User host address: xx.xx.xx.91 

User:  
    Is authenticated: False 

Authentication Type:  

Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 


Thread information: 

Thread ID: 18 

Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 

Is impersonating: False 

Stack trace:    at ADODB.ConnectionClass.set_ConnectionString(String pbstr)
   at clsCalc_IllustrationValues.mod_DLLUtilities.util_OpenMyDBConnection(String& strDBName, String& strPassword) in C:\MyFiles\Visual Studio Projects   \clsCalc_IllustrationValues\mod_DLLUtilities.vb:line 130
   at clsCalc_IllustrationValues.clsConvertedActVal.GetPlanData(Int32& eLOB_ActValCalcs, usrUserInputType& usrUserInput, usrPolicyValuesType&    usrPolicyValues) in C:\MyFiles\Visual Studio Projects\clsCalc_IllustrationValues\clsConvertedActVal.vb:line 2668
   at clsCalc_IllustrationValues.clsConvertedActVal.TradSolve() in C:\MyFiles\Visual Studio Projects\clsCalc_IllustrationValues\clsConvertedActVal.vb:line    2063
   at clsCalc_IllustrationValues.clsActValDotNet.DoSingleSolve(DataSet dsDataSet) in C:\MyFiles\Visual Studio Projects\clsCalc_IllustrationValues   \clsActValDotNet.vb:line 945
   at _Default.CallSingleSolve() in C:\inetpub-illustrations\wwwroot\Default.aspx.vb:line 2997
   at _Default.InitializeAllControls() in C:\inetpub-illustrations\wwwroot\Default.aspx.vb:line 354
   at _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\inetpub-illustrations\wwwroot\Default.aspx.vb:line 65
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
Custom event details: 

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="32768">1309</EventID>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>3</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-08-06T19:48:00.000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>30445</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>358797-web1</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>3005</Data>
    <Data>An unhandled exception has occurred.</Data>
    <Data>8/6/2013 2:48:00 PM</Data>
    <Data>8/6/2013 7:48:00 PM</Data>
    <Data>ca3280fb485345c194349a42e6e81a85</Data>
    <Data>66</Data>
    <Data>11</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>/LM/W3SVC/12/ROOT-1-130202909916484475</Data>
    <Data>Full</Data>
    <Data>/</Data>
    <Data>C:\inetpub-illustrations\wwwroot\</Data>
    <Data>358797-WEB1</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>760</Data>
    <Data>w3wp.exe</Data>
    <Data>NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM</Data>
    <Data>COMException</Data>
    <Data>Operation is not allowed when the object is open.
   at ADODB.ConnectionClass.set_ConnectionString(String pbstr)
   at clsCalc_IllustrationValues.mod_DLLUtilities.util_OpenMyDBConnection(String&amp; strDBName, String&amp; strPassword) in C:\MyFiles\Visual Studio    Projects\clsCalc_IllustrationValues\mod_DLLUtilities.vb:line 130
   at clsCalc_IllustrationValues.clsConvertedActVal.GetPlanData(Int32&amp; eLOB_ActValCalcs, usrUserInputType&amp; usrUserInput, usrPolicyValuesType&amp;    usrPolicyValues) in C:\MyFiles\Visual Studio Projects\clsCalc_IllustrationValues\clsConvertedActVal.vb:line 2668
   at clsCalc_IllustrationValues.clsConvertedActVal.TradSolve() in C:\MyFiles\Visual Studio Projects\clsCalc_IllustrationValues\clsConvertedActVal.vb:line    2063
   at clsCalc_IllustrationValues.clsActValDotNet.DoSingleSolve(DataSet dsDataSet) in C:\MyFiles\Visual Studio Projects\clsCalc_IllustrationValues   \clsActValDotNet.vb:line 945
   at _Default.CallSingleSolve() in C:\inetpub-illustrations\wwwroot\Default.aspx.vb:line 2997
   at _Default.InitializeAllControls() in C:\inetpub-illustrations\wwwroot\Default.aspx.vb:line 354
   at _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\inetpub-illustrations\wwwroot\Default.aspx.vb:line 65
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

</Data>
    <Data>http://xx.xx.xx.250/Default.aspx</Data>
    <Data>/Default.aspx</Data>
    <Data>xx.xx.xx.91</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>False</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM</Data>
    <Data>18</Data>
    <Data>NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM</Data>
    <Data>False</Data>
    <Data>   at ADODB.ConnectionClass.set_ConnectionString(String pbstr)
   at clsCalc_IllustrationValues.mod_DLLUtilities.util_OpenMyDBConnection(String&amp; strDBName, String&amp; strPassword) in C:\MyFiles\Visual Studio
   Projects\clsCalc_IllustrationValues\mod_DLLUtilities.vb:line 130
   at clsCalc_IllustrationValues.clsConvertedActVal.GetPlanData(Int32&amp; eLOB_ActValCalcs, usrUserInputType&amp; usrUserInput, usrPolicyValuesType&amp;    usrPolicyValues) in C:\MyFiles\Visual Studio Projects\clsCalc_IllustrationValues\clsConvertedActVal.vb:line 2668
   at clsCalc_IllustrationValues.clsConvertedActVal.TradSolve() in C:\MyFiles\Visual Studio Projects\clsCalc_IllustrationValues\clsConvertedActVal.vb:line    2063
   at clsCalc_IllustrationValues.clsActValDotNet.DoSingleSolve(DataSet dsDataSet) in C:\MyFiles\Visual Studio Projects\clsCalc_IllustrationValues   \clsActValDotNet.vb:line 945
   at _Default.CallSingleSolve() in C:\inetpub-illustrations\wwwroot\Default.aspx.vb:line 2997
   at _Default.InitializeAllControls() in C:\inetpub-illustrations\wwwroot\Default.aspx.vb:line 354
   at _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\inetpub-illustrations\wwwroot\Default.aspx.vb:line 65
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

**FOLLOWUP UPDATE** (I looked at help - I think I am doing this right by editing the original question. Let me know if I should follow up in a different manner). There is more I am trying to narrow down the problem (so I understand if anyone waits to answer), but I wanted to update with code as asked.

First, thanks for editing the sensitive info above - I did not realize that was an issue. Anyway, I discovered that an old part of my code (where I think the error was) was accessing the database using different code, so I updated it and consolidated so that all my database access is happening in the same code:

```
Private Function GetDataSet_ODBC() As System.Data.DataSet

    Dim dsDataSet As New System.Data.DataSet

    If Me.bWriteToTraceFile Then Me.WriteToTextFile("START GetDataSet_ODBC", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "..\TraceFiles\TraceODBC.txt", False)
    Dim DataAdapter As New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter
    If Me.bWriteToTraceFile Then Me.WriteToTextFile("  Created DataAdapter", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "..\TraceFiles\TraceODBC.txt", True)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iUBound As Integer
    Dim iRetryCount As Integer
    Dim dStart As Double
    Dim dFinish As Double

    DataAdapter.SelectCommand = New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand
    If Me.bWriteToTraceFile Then Me.WriteToTextFile("  Created new command", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "..\TraceFiles\TraceODBC.txt", True)
    With DataAdapter.SelectCommand
        .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        .Connection = New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
        .Connection.ConnectionTimeout = 15
        .Connection.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};" & _
            "DBQ=" & tDBPath & tDBName & ";UID=;PWD=" & tDBPassword
        If Me.bWriteToTraceFile Then Me.WriteToTextFile("  ConnectionString=" & .Connection.ConnectionString, System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "..\TraceFiles\TraceODBC.txt", True)
    End With

    DataAdapter.InsertCommand = New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand
    With DataAdapter.InsertCommand
        .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        .Connection = DataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection
    End With
    DataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection.Open()
    If Me.bWriteToTraceFile Then Me.WriteToTextFile("  Connection opened", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "..\TraceFiles\TraceODBC.txt", True)
    iUBound = UBound(usrProcedures)
    For i = 0 To iUBound
        DataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "Execute " & usrProcedures(i).tName & " " & usrProcedures(i).tParameters
        iRetryCount = 0
        Do
            Try
                If Me.bWriteToTraceFile Then Me.WriteToTextFile("  Executing... " & Str(i) & " " & usrProcedures(i).tName, System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "..\TraceFiles\TraceODBC.txt", True)
                DataAdapter.Fill(dsDataSet, usrProcedures(i).tTableName)
                If Me.bWriteToTraceFile Then Me.WriteToTextFile("  Wrote to " & usrProcedures(i).tTableName, System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "..\TraceFiles\TraceODBC.txt", True)
                Exit Do
            Catch
                iRetryCount += 1
                If iRetryCount = 25 Then
                    If Me.bWriteToTraceFile Then Me.WriteToTextFile("  Still won't work", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "..\TraceFiles\TraceODBC.txt", True)
                    Exit Do
                End If
                dStart = Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.Timer
                dFinish = dStart + 1
                Do Until Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.Timer > dFinish
                Loop
                If Me.bWriteToTraceFile Then Me.WriteToTextFile("  Try again " & Str(iRetryCount) & " " & Str(dStart) & Str(Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.Timer), System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "..\TraceFiles\TraceODBC.txt", True)
            End Try
        Loop
    Next
    DataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection.Close()
    If Me.bWriteToTraceFile Then Me.WriteToTextFile("  Connection closed", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "..\TraceFiles\TraceODBC.txt", True)

    DataAdapter = Nothing
    If Me.bWriteToTraceFile Then Me.WriteToTextFile("FINISH GetDataSet_ODBC", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "..\TraceFiles\TraceODBC.txt", True)

    Return dsDataSet

End Function
```

I also promoted the built code to the server without "DEBUG" turned on to speed things up. That may have been a mistake while debugging (I will undo that). Now when two people hit the database at the same time it just hangs on the second guy. However, now I can close the second guys browser, go back in, and run the app ok without having to restart the website. I experimented with the # of retries and am working on a trace file to see where things hang up, but maybe something sticks out for you.

FYI - The code above accepts an array of usrProcedure() which has the name of the stored Access parameter query, the parameters, and the name of the datatable I want returned. There may be as many as 10 mostly small tables (many just 1 record, maybe one or two with 100 records) returned in a dataset. I try to hit the database only a few times, but maybe I overdo that retrieving too much data at once? But I have a pretty powerful server (I think) (dedicated Window Server 2008 Enterprise, Version 6.0 Build 6002, SP2, 64bit, 8gb RAM, AMD 2200 Mhz 4 core processor - almost no traffic at this time, hosted by Rackspace).

Anyway, I am guessing (but will try to verify thru the trace), that the second guy either ends up looping thru the Tries and hangs later because of no data, or is hanging on a Try.

Finally, I hit this database access code in two places (one to retrieve input control data and the other to do calcs). The first time the code is being called from my uncompiled code behind page. That never seems to hang (although accessing about the same amount of data if not more). The code above is in a compiled DLL "utilities" project. The second time, this code is called from another DLL project that does my calculations. This is where things hang. Not sure if that is relevant, but just trying to list all patterns/clues.

Does the code listed provide any clues?

Thanks in advance,
Chuck

**FOLLOWUP UPDATE #2** OK, I wrote to trace files (using SessionID as part of the filename) throughout the code to try to pinpoint where the error actually occurs. The problem that still occurs is when two users hit the application at the same time. One runs successfully and the other has an unhandled 3005 error. However, the error now is NOT the "trying to open" error mentioned above (so apparently I fixed that). Now the 3005 error occurs at various points in the code, usually indicating in the Event viewer that there is a null variable at some line. Each user is making the identical request and so should get identical results. My trace files tell me I am reading the same # of records from the database in both user instances, but one of the instances gets the error sometime after reading the data. I have lots of code and the error occurs at different points, so I am not sure what to post. I am now capturing the error in the Global.asax file to redirect the user to re-log in and run the application again. The app runs fine the 2nd time when run alone.

It sure seems like the two instances are somehow not completely independent of each other and that one somehow is erasing objects or data from the other. It seems like the error occurs at different points based on the precise timing of when the requests hit the server. The date stamps I put in the trace files seem to indicate that the one instance errs about when the other instance finishes the request. I have checked for Shared routines and eliminated those. I have checked to make sure each instance of a DLL called is declared "as New". Also, I noticed that the lines written to the trace files do not always show up in the order that they should per the code.

Does ASP.NET automatically do any asynchronous running of the code without me doing anything special and could that be messing things up? I have not tried to do any async stuff explicitly because it seems complicated, but do I need to manage something here?

What else should I be looking for?

Thanks in advance again

Comment: I masked the IP addresses. You'll want to be more careful with sensitive information.

Comment: More investigative info - The second user always "kicks the first user out", so it seems that some initialization of variables is leaking into the first session? Also, sometimes even the second user has some bad data introduced even though it runs all the way thru.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. Hopefully, this will help somebody else with a similar problem.

Turns out I had some important variables globally declared in a regular code module instead of in the class module, all part of one project in my Visual Studio solution. **I did not realize that only the code and variables in the class module is kept separate for each user on the server.** I was thrown off by the fact that they all get compiled together into the same DLL file and so was thinking the entire DLL was "copied". The realization came when I captured the error in the Global.asax, aborted the session, and redirected page. Then I could clearly see that the second user was immediately causing the first user to err out when the variables were getting re-initialized (originally, I was thinking it was the second user erring out). A little googling then told me what I needed to know.

I think this was also actually the cause of the original database issue described above. Some old code that I missed somehow, was accessing the database from the regular code modules, causing conflicts with the database. That got fixed when I got rid of that code and converted to retrieving the data from my class module that I now use to access the database (although I did not realize at the time how that fixed it).

So once I moved all the variable declarations into the class module and did some massive changes to pass variables thru arguments to the regular module code in my Subroutines, problem fixed (so far at least).

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting is that you are trying to open a connection that is already open. There may be an issue with how you're disposing of your connection. Code would be nice to see.

Also, you should ALWAYS take into consideration multiple people hitting the DB at the same time. Try opening your application in multiple tabs, you'll probably see the same issue happen.

Comment: I updated my question with more info above. Let me know if that is not the right way to do that.